# Why won't <meta http-equiv="refresh" ... /> work? Nothing happens?

Tags: html, redirect, refresh, meta-tags

I've added a meta refresh to my page, but nothing happens at all.
I'm using

```
<meta http-equiv="refesh" content="0;URL=http://buzztard.org/"/>
```

I'm in Google Chrome too.

Comment: refresh, not refesh?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you misspelled "refresh" as "refesh". You need an "r" between f and e.

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=http://buzztard.org/"/>
```

Missed that pesky "r" :)